# Mac で USB メモリ上のデータを維持したままパーティションを操作したい

Tags: macos, ubuntu, usb

LinuxとWindowsの入ったUSBを作るためにUSBにパーティションを割り当てようとしています．
そこで質問ですがパーティションとは一度作ってしまうと再変更することはできないものなのでしょうか？というのもUSBの中身を消さずにということです．

例えば，私はdiskutilを使ってUbuntuとWindowsようにそれぞれ10Gのパーティションを割り当てました．また，残りの領域は一つのパーティションとして残しています．そういった場合，その残されたパーティションはのちに2つに分けたり，UbuntuとWindowsのパーティションにOSを入れた後にそのパーティションの大きさを変更したりすることは後になってから可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

パーティションのデータを維持したままの操作は `parted` コマンドや、その GUI フロントエンドの GParted が有名です。

Mac 環境では試したことがありませんが、Windows であれば実際にリサイズ等を実施したことがあります。
ただし元のファイルシステムによっては移動やリサイズが不可な場合もありますし、この手の操作を行う場合には万一に備えて事前にバックアップを取っておくことをお勧めします。

Mac だと直接 GParted を入れるのは難しそうですが、VirtualBox や Docker 上で動かしたという方法もあるようです。コマンドでの操作でもよければ若干操作の難易度は挙がりますが、parted コマンドを試してもよさそうです。

**参考:**
[Install GParted on a mac with Homebrew or Macports? - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/621579)